# for each module reference between modules with a map object

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

im trying to create an instance group with reference to an GCE, but im unable to refer to the id from instance group to link to the GCE

```
variable "compute_engine_instances" {
  type = map(object({
    instance_name = string
    machine_type  = string
    zone          = string
    tags          = list(string)
    image_name    = string
    image_project = string
    labels        =object({
    app_id      = number
    cost_center = string
    owner       = string
    email       = string
  })
  }))
}
module "qat_hosted_pacs_compute_engines" {
  source = "../modules/compute_engine"

  for_each      = var.compute_engine_instances
  project_id    = var.project_id
  instance_name = each.value.instance_name
  machine_type  = each.value.machine_type
  tags          = each.value.tags
  labels        = each.value.labels
  subnetwork    = var.subnetwork
  zone          = each.value.zone
  image_name    = each.value.image_name
  image_project = each.value.image_project
}
```

```
variable "instance_group" {
  type = map(object({
    group_manager_name = string
    zone = string
  }))
  
}
module "qat_hosted_pacs_app_grp" {
  source             = "../modules/instance_groups"
  for_each = var.instance_group
  group_manager_name = each.value.group_manager_name
  zone               = each.value.zone
  project_id         = var.project_id
  instances          = module.qat_hosted_pacs_compute_engines.vm_name   #unable to figure out how to reference the GCE
}
```

#output.tf looks like this for compute engine module

```
output "compute_engine_instances" {
  value = {
    for k, v in module.qat_hosted_pacs_compute_engines : k => v.vm_name
  }
}
```

The root module looks like this for compute engine

```
data "google_compute_image" "compute_image" {
  name    = var.image_name
  project = var.image_project
}

resource "google_compute_instance" "generic_instance" {
  project      = var.project_id
  name         = var.instance_name
  machine_type = var.machine_type
  zone         = var.zone

  tags   = var.tags
  labels = var.labels

  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = data.google_compute_image.compute_image.self_link
    }
    auto_delete = true
  }

  network_interface {
    subnetwork = var.subnetwork
  }
}
```

#outputs.tf here looks like this for gce resource

```
output "vm_name" {
  value       = google_compute_instance.generic_instance.id
  description = "The name of the VM"
}
```

And the instance group manager looks like this

```
resource "google_compute_instance_group" "igm" {
  name    = var.group_manager_name
  zone    = var.zone
  project = var.project_id

  instances = var.instances
  named_port {
    name = "http"
    port = "8080"
  }

  named_port {
    name = "https"
    port = "8443"
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}
```

i get the foll. error

```
Error: Unsupported attribute

  on main.tf line 45, in module "qat_hosted_pacs_app_grp":
  45:   instances          = module.qat_hosted_pacs_compute_engines.vm_name
    |----------------
    | module.qat_hosted_pacs_compute_engines is object with 2 attributes

This object does not have an attribute named "vm_name".
```

terraform tf vars file

```
compute_engine_instances ={
    "test-adi"={

    instance_name = "test-vm"
    machine_type  = "n1-standard-1"
    zone           = "us-east4-b"
    tags   = ["foo","bar"]
    image_name    = "gold-centos-7"
    image_project = "dev-cietools"
    labels = {
  app_id      = "56"
  cost_center = "156"
  owner       = "ops"
  email       = "ops"
}}
    "test-adi-2"={

    instance_name = "test-vm-2"
    machine_type  = "n1-standard-1"
    zone           = "us-east4-b"
    tags   = ["foo","bar"]
    image_name    = "centos-7"
    image_project = "dev-cietools"
    labels = {
  app_id      = "56"
  cost_center = "856"
  owner       = "ops"
  email       = "ops"
}
}
}
subnetwork = "sandbox-us-east4"
project_id = "cloudops-dev01-sb"


instance_group = {
  "igm" = {
    group_manager_name = "test"
    zone = "us-east4-b"
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the relationship between `var.instance_group` and  `var.compute_engine_instances`? Sadly you have provided any example of their values, thus its difficult to guess what do you do.

Comment: instances          = module.qat_hosted_pacs_compute_engines.vm_name

Comment: You can't use ` module.qat_hosted_pacs_compute_engines.vm_name` because you use for_each in `qat_hosted_pacs_compute_engines`. How to fix that, depends on what are the values of your variabiles, which you are not showing.

Comment: @Marcin added the tfvars values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you used `for_each` in your `google_compute_instance_group` module, you have to use key to refer to individual instances of the module, e.g.

```
 instances          = module.qat_hosted_pacs_compute_engines["test-adi"].vm_name
```

or if you want to pass all `vm_name` created for all values of `for_each`, you can do:

```
instances          = values(module.qat_hosted_pacs_compute_engines)[*].vm_name
```